# Mercurial: How do I fix an incorrectly published rename/copy?

Tags: mercurial

I've somehow marked a bunch of files as being "copy/renamed" instead of just marking them as new files.
I've also published these changes to our central repository and can cannot strip them out (we've already got some changes on top and I don't have the permissions/ability to fiddle with the central repository anyway).

**Context:**

I've actually done it to a whole bunch of files, but here's an example of what I did to one: I've copied a file called "Labels.properties", to a new file called "Labels_ja.properties" (the new file contains a subset of the original properties, and eventually all the values will be translated to a different language). The "Labels_ja.properties" file has been marked as a copy/rename of "Labels.properties" (the only way I've been able to see exactly what's happened is by looking with SourceTree, which shows "File copied/renamed from Labels.properties").

Our environment is a sort of central repository with automated "pull request" style merging tools built on top, so solutions involving all our developers magically knowing exactly how to drive Hg in order to resolve these conflicts aren't going to work - it's the scripts that are getting the merge conflicts.

These copy/renames are causing a lot of hassles: when people touch the original versions of the property files (they don't even know about the copied files yet) - it looks like Hg is trying to merge those changes onto the copies, but because the files are very different, those merges are failing with conflicts.

**Problem:**

What can I do to sort out all these merge conflicts that our automated merge scripts are getting?
Ideally, I'd like to go back in time and just mark all these files "new" - but there's no going back now that the changesets have been published.

Can I just make a big backout commit, then re-add the files (making sure that they are marked "new" and not "copy/renamed")?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a good solution. Even if you delete the files, Mercurial will still complain repeatedly when they get changed and merged. The simplest solution I can think of is moving the bad files into some "attic" directory where they don't hurt anyone and never touching them again. Then add the real files where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is in fact that the developers are still based on a revision that does not have your move.

When they change the original file, an 'hg merge' will then smash together the changes from the developer and the changes to the new file in that new file.

I see a few solutions for this:

- <s>You can tell the developers to rebase their changes on top of the new changes.</s> This will actually not work, since rebase will make the same mistake as merge.
- The developers can turn their changes into patches and apply their patches on top of your changes. Their patches will refer to the original files, not the changed files, so this should work fine for the tools that merge later on.
- The above flow can be done in a more sophisticated way using Mercurial Queues: import the existing developer commits as patches, then qpop all of these, update to your newer revision and qpush all of the revisions again.
- Mark the head with your changes as 'closed' using '--close-branch'. However, if your tools are not equipped to handle this correctly (by ignoring the closed branch), this may cause issues. Branches are reopened when a new commit is done on top of the branch. So if you merge developer changes with the closed branch, it will open again.